# Adding a 'domainMax' property to an existing Vega visualisation using Vincent

Tags: python, pandas, vega, vincent

I'm creating a StackedBar viz using Vincent in Python. Data is from a pandas dataframe, with each column representing a percentage and each row sums to 100%

Vincent / Vega is trying to be helpful and adding a buffer to the Y axis so that it maxes out at 110 (%) when I want to be 100.

The property I need to add is 'domainMax' in the grammar for the Y scale, but I can't work out how to use Vincent's PropertySet or similar commands to add this in after importing the Pandas dataframe.

Here's an example of the data with domainMax added in manually, can anyone advise on how to do this in Python

```
"scales": [
    {
      "domain": {
        "data": "table",
        "field": "data.idx"
      },
      "name": "x",
      "range": "width",
      "type": "ordinal"
    },
    {
      "domain": {
        "data": "stats",
        "field": "sum"
      },
      "name": "y",
      "nice": true,
      "range": "height",
      "type": "linear",
      "domainMax": 100  
    }
```

[...]

Answer (score 2):

Problem was that Vincent and Vega using slightly different naming conventions, and this wasn't explicitly in the Vincent docs.

Vega has "domainMax" on their docs [1] whereas the Vincent property you need to target is "domain_max", found within Scales.py [2]

So the solution was: `chart.scales[ref].domain_max = value`

In practice:

```
chart = vincent.StackedBar(dataframe)
chart.scales[1].domain_max = 100
chart.display()
```

[1] https://github.com/trifacta/vega/wiki/Scales

[2] https://github.com/wrobstory/vincent/blob/master/vincent/scales.py#L77

Comment: I should be more explicit in the Vincent docs about this- everything camel-cased in Vega has been python-icized with an underscore instead. Additionally, any Vega params that are reserved words in Python have been prepended with an underscore.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @RobStory - appreciate the clarity. Let me know if there's anything I could do to support, I think it's a great library overall.